# Splitting field for $x^2 + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Let $f(x) = x^2 + 1 \in \Bbb Q[x]$.  Since $x^2+1 = (x + \sqrt{-1})(x-\sqrt{-1})$, we see that $f(x)$ splits in $\Bbb C$, but a splitting field over $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb Q(i) = \{r + si : r,s, \in \Bbb Q\}$.

Why is this the splitting field?  What makes this the smallest field extension that $f(x)$ splits in?  I can't figure why this is.

Comment: I guess it's easy to see that $x^2+1$ splits over $\textbf{Q}(i)$ but not spits over any extension field of $\textbf{Q}$ which is smaller than $\textbf{Q}(i)$ (what are they)?

Comment: Every field extension of $\Bbb Q$ contains $\Bbb Q$; and a splitting field of $x^2+1$ contains $i$. What's the smallest field with those two properties?

Comment: @GregMartin It seems to be $\{a+bi:a,b \in \Bbb Q \}$, but I don't know how to show that it's the smallest.

Comment: ($i$ is by a definition a root of $x^2+1$) so $K$ the splitting field of $x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ contains $i$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ (by definition). and since $x^2+1 $ splits in $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$, this field has to be the smallest where it does

Comment: @user1952009 But why is it the smallest?  Why can you be sure that there are no smaller fields that are splitting fields?

Comment: @OliverG I explained that. And note that the splitting field of $x^2-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is $\mathbb{Q}(1,-1) = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The point is, any field that contains both $\Bbb Q$ and $i$ *has* to contain every element of the form $a+bi$ ... just because fields are closed under addition and multiplication. So there can't be any smaller field, because every such field already contains $\Bbb Q[i]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be an extension of $\Bbb Q$ (with $j : \Bbb Q \to K$) such that $X^2+1$ splits over $K$, say $X^2+1=(X-a)(X-b)$ with $a,b \in K$. We know that $b=-a$ since $(-a)^2=a^2=1$.

Let $K' := j(\Bbb Q) \subset K$, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ (since $j$ is injective). Then there is a (unique) field morphism

$$\phi : \Bbb Q(i) \subset \Bbb C \longrightarrow K'(a,b)=K'(a) \subset K$$ 
which extends $j$ and such that $\phi(i) = a$.

By injectivity of $\phi$ (it is a field morphism), we get that $K$ is an extension of $\Bbb Q(i)$. Moreover, $X^2+1$ clearly splits over $\Bbb Q(i)$.

This shows that $L:=\Bbb Q(i)$ is *the* splitting field of $X^2+1$ over $\Bbb Q$, because 
$X^2+1$ splits over $L$, and if $X^2+1$ splits over some $K$, then $K$ is an extension of $L$.